# WPF Mouse Position not retrieved properly

Tags: c#, wpf

Disclosure:  This is my first WPF app.  Please be accepting of my ignorance.

In my WPF application, I have a ControlTemplate with a Grid and various children beneath that.  In the code-behind, I am dynamically adding a custom ContentControl element using the ControlTemplate.

When the new Control is created, it is intended to capture the mouse and allow dragging capabilities.  The code for the dragging calculations is fine if the Grid has already been loaded on the window and I have the start Point set to MouseButtonEventArgs.GetPosition(window).  But when the event is fired when the Grid is initially loaded, the Point is equal to the inverse position of the window.  E.g. if my window is at (350,250), my start Point is (-350,-250).

```
private void GridLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e) { // fires MouseLeftButtonDown event for grid}

private void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    ...
    m_start = e.GetPosition(this); // 'this' is the current window; returns the inverse coordinates of 'this'
    ...
}
```

Is there a more appropriate method to get the x,y coordinates of my mouse position.  I could work with screen coordinates if necessary, but all code I've found uses what would be PointToScreen(m_start).  This is useless as m_start is incorrect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both WPF and WIndows Forms already have drag & drop support, including DragEnter, DragOver, Drop events. You should handle the proper events instead of trying to capture the mouse position. Check [Drag & Drop Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742859(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Drag and Drop only handles movement on the parent window, correct?  I tried to implement it before, but a requirement of application is the ability to drag the control from the window. (Think tabs on browser)

Comment: No. Otherwise there wouldn't be much point in a DragEnter event. Drag&Drop is a *Windows* operation, not a visual effect. It doesn't even have to start with a click&drag, your application can signal a drag start programmatically with DoDragDrop. The controls toolbox in Visual Studio for example, initiates a drag when you *click* on a control.

Comment: Great.  I suppose I'll look more into that then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try, I snagged this some time ago and it worked well for me:

```cs
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public static implicit operator Point(POINT point)
        {
            return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

    public static Point GetCursorPosition()
    {
        POINT lpPoint;
        GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
        //bool success = User32.GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
        // if (!success)

        return lpPoint;
    }
```

Comment: This will get the position of the mouse relative to your entire screen. If I had to guess this isn't what OP would want.

Comment: I'm attempting to convert everything to use DragDrop methods per the comments on the question.  This may work though as I'd be able to compare the window's position with mouse position and get that as my offset.  Thanks for actually answering my question, Athena

Comment: So when I implement this method, GetCursorPosition is returning something like (4.73e-312,0).  Anything obvious that I messed up?  Because that is clearly wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the delay rosst, I added the necessary edit for the POINT struct.